# Create rss feed from tumblr website

Tags: xml, rss, tumblr, feed

I am new here :)
I 'm trying to create an Rss feed from a website, which appears to be a tumblr blog. When I open websiteurl/rss I get the error message:
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show us your code or we can't help you.

Comment: That isn't an error message … or a anything other than expected behaviour for an RSS feed.